# Integration tests fail - autowiring issue with Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, integration-testing, autowired, cglib

For whatever reason, when I try to run any integration test, I'm getting the following:

```
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property     
value of type    
'myproject.provider.shipping.variable.ConcreteImplService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f28ea3b8' to 
required type 'ammoscanner.provider.shipping.variable.ConcreteImplService' for property 
'concreteImplService'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot 
convert value of type
```

Why is CGLib wrapping my injected classes and causing tests to fail? I'm running grails 1.3.6 and running tests through Intelli-J ultimate 10.01.

Comment: Does it work when running the same code in run-app or in a war? Also,what plugins are you using in your app?

Comment: Also try running from the commandline to eliminate IntelliJ as a variable.

Comment: run-app and as a war work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebuilt and restarted IntelliJ, and all was well.